# A strange .append error

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a simple sort fiddle, with a hard to debug error: it doesn't .append, on the other hand alert(data) is working, so this is not a ajax issue. Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Enter a sequence with spaces:</div>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" id="n" name="numbers">
<button>Sort</button>
</form>
<div>The sorted sequence is: <span id="s"></span></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){$("form").submit(function({$.post("/tests/sort.php",$(this).serialize(),function(data){JSON.parse(data);$("#s").append(data);});})});
</script>

</html>
```

with the php

```
<?php

$s=$_POST["numbers"];
$a=explode(" ",$s);
sort($a);
echo json_encode($a);

?>
```

Can anybody please spot the error?

Comment: is there any error in your browser's console?

Comment: What about `$("#s").html(data)` or `$("#s").text(data)`?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your js code

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in comment for your question you have an error in JS code. To avoid errors like this you have to edit code for better reading. Here is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function () {
        $.post("/tests/sort.php", $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
            JSON.parse(data);
            $("#s").append(data);
        });
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a right parenthesis `)` and a semicolon `;`. You can use [jshint.com](http://jshint.com/) to check your syntax, and should indent your code so it is easily readable:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        $.post("/tests/sort.php",$(this).serialize(),function(data){
            JSON.parse(data);$("#s").append(data);
        });
    });
});
```